# Why isn't the 'number' value changing?

Tags: c++, function

I'm trying to make a function that reduces a certain integer value by 30.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int valuered(int value)
{
    value-=30;
}

int main()
{
    int number{100};
    valuered(number);
    cout<<number;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This variable is being passed by value, not by reference. Read on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value

Comment: It's also [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/return) to reach the end of a value-returning function like `valuered` without actually returning anything.

Comment: You need a reference `void valuered(int& value)`

Answer (score 7):

You are passing `value` by value, meaning the `valuered` function has a local copy of the argument. If you want to affect the outside variable `number` the function should look like this:

```cpp
void valuered(int& value)
{
    value-=30;
}
```

Here `value` is being passed by reference, meaning any changes done to it inside the function will propagate to the actual argument that has been passed in.

Also note that I have changed the return type from `int` to `void`, since you are not returning anything. Not returning anything from a function declared to return a value makes the program have [*undefined behavior*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 0):

pass by reference is important to use the modified value out side the  function because if you are using pass by value then the change in value will only exist inside the user defined function.

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int valuered(int &v) // pass  by reference is needed to use the modified value in main function.
{
    v-=30;
    return v;
}
int main()
{
    int number=100;
    valuered(number);
    cout<<number;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).